# INNER JOIN issue with MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

Does any one know what is incorrect in the query below?

```
SELECT S1.[Company], COUNT(S1.[Milestone]) AS ShouldBeMilestones

FROM Sheet1 AS S1

INNER JOIN Sheet1 S2
ON S2.[Company] = S1.[Company]
AND S2.[Project] = S1.[Project]
AND S2.[Milestone] = 'Milestone 1'
AND S2.[%compl#] = 100

INNER JOIN Sheet1 S3
ON S3.[Company] = S1.[Company]
AND S3.[Project] = S1.[Project]
AND S3.[Milestone] = 'Milestone 2'
AND S3.[%compl#] = 100

WHERE ((S1.[Task class] <> 'A') AND (S1.[Task class] <> 'B') AND (S1.[Task class] <> ''))
AND S1.[Milestone] NOT LIKE '0.*' AND S1.[Milestone] NOT LIKE '1.*'
AND S1.[Start] <= Now()

GROUP BY S1.[Company];
```

I am getting a "Syntax Error in FROM clause" message when running it in a MS Access 2010...

Any idea would be appreciated!

Thanks,

Comment: I _think_ (but can't remember with certainty) that Access requires multiple joins to be `(())` enclosed. So `FROM (((Sheet1 AS s1) INNER JOIN Sheet1 S2 ON .....) INNER JOIN Sheet1 S3 ON ....)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS Access SQL is strange in that you have to put parentheses around the `JOIN`s in multi-JOIN queries.  I hate this feature and have yet to solve the "logic" behind it myself.  You might have luck re-building a simple version of this in Access query-builder, and then editing it without messing with the parentheses.

Comment: I actually wrote it through the SQL editor. tried to build it through the wizard but it doesnt work. no idea how to start though with the parentheses. Do you have a suggestion? Thanks!!!

Comment: I don't want to steal credit; @MichaelBerkowski seems to have an idea in the comment to your question.

Comment: Hi coge. By doing what michael suggested I got a new message error: "JOIN NOT SUPPORTED"

Comment: can you add to your original post your new code?  (leave your original if you can, it helps show the progression of the solution)

Comment: perhaps this link will help? http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/accessdev/thread/15c36745-f7a4-4926-9687-7161e5894468